# Double faces for curve mesh

Tags: mesh, faces

I need to know how to do double face on objects created via curve mesh. I created this using curve path and used the "bevel object" on another curve. It created the slide that I needed. When I tried to import the 3D object as fbx for unity, the slide has face only on the surface but the moment you look from the bottom, it becomes transparent, obviously the face on the bottom is reversed. Please help.

[image: Picture A]

[image: Picture B]

Comment: Before exporting convert curve object to mesh and in Edit mode recalculate its normals.

Answer (score 0):

Add a solidify modifier to the object, this will create two sides to the object.

[image: Add Solidify Modifier]